# How to call java method using javascript in ZK MVVM?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, mvvm, zk

I am using Edraw Office Viewer component to open & edit the file. I want to save my file to my destination point so I am using JavaScript to save the file. But I am stuck at a point. I am showing my code below to save document using JavaScript.

```
function f_saveDocument(){
    if(document.OA1.IsOpened)           
    {   
    var saveAsFileName = document.getElementById('hdnFileName').value;
    alert(saveAsFileName);
        var fileFormat = saveAsFileName.substring(saveAsFileName.lastIndexOf("."));
        if(fileFormat == '.docx') {
            var toUnLockFile = 'MergeTest'+fileFormat;
            var tempFileLocation = document.OA1.GetTempFilePath(saveAsFileName);
            var tempToUnLockFileLocation = document.OA1.GetTempFilePath(toUnLockFile);
            document.OA1.SaveAs(tempFileLocation,12);
            document.OA1.SaveAs(tempToUnLockFileLocation,12);
            document.OA1.HttpInit();
            document.OA1.HttpAddPostFile(tempFileLocation);
              document.OA1.HttpPost(""); 
            document.OA1.ClearTempFiles();
        } else {
        alert("asdsa");
            document.OA1.HttpInit();
            document.OA1.HttpAddPostOpenedFile(saveAsFileName);
             **zAu.send(new zk.Event(zk.Widget.$('$btnSave'), "saveFile", {'' : {'data' : {'nodeId': ''}}}, {toServer:true}));** 
         alert("moved");
        }

    }
```

In case of JSP page I can put my JSP URL in `HttpPost` but in case of ZK how to move from this JavaScript to Java method. So to overcome this problem I am using Widget to call `saveFile()` method which is in my `viewmodel` class. But `zAu.send` is not working fine. Can any body tell other solution to call my Java method from JavaScript in ZK MVVM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is simply wrong

```
zAu.send(new zk.Event(zk.Widget.$('$btnSave'), "onSaveFile", {'' : {'data' : {'nodeId': ''}}}, {toServer:true}));
```

Event names must start with `on` so this will fire a `onSaveFile`
event to the `Component` with id `btnSave`. Just [listen](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/Advance/Wire_Event_Listeners) to it.

Comment: Nabil: I have one more Question...Is there any way to pass zk url in HttpPost?Actually I want to get request in java method for MultipartRequest.

 MultipartRequest mr = new MultipartRequest(request, savePath, 50000000);